# How to limit upper bound of enum classes?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have an interface look like this.

```java
interface MyEnum<E extends Enum<E> & MyEnum<E>> {

    static <E extends Enum<E> & MyEnum<E, T>, T> E valueOfAttribute(
            Class<E> enumClass, T attributeValue) {
        for (final E enumConstant : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (Objects.equals(enumConstant.attribute(), attributeValue)) {
                return enumConstant;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "no enum constant, from " + enumClass
                + ", for " + attributeValue);
    }

    T attribute();
}
```

And let us all say that I have the following classes.

```java
interface YourEnum<E extends YourEnum<E> & YourEnum<E>>
        extends MyEnum<E, String> {

    @Override public String attribute() { return ((Enum<?>) this).name(); }
}

enum HisEnum implements YourEnum<HisEnum> {
    HIS
}

enum HerEnum implements YourEnum<HerEnum> {
    HER
}
```

And I want to add another utility class for finding the enum constant matches to specific attribute value among one or more enum classes implements same subtype of `MyEnum`.

```java
// should find HisEnum#HIS
MyEnum.<YourEnum>valueOfAttribute("HIS", HisEnum.class, HerEnum.class);
```

How can I add a `static` utility method which finds the first enum constant whose `attribute()` matches to specified value, from one or more enum classes extends a specific sub-interface of `MyEnum`?

I'm, so far, trying with this.

```java
    // TODO: Scream!
    static <T extends MyEnum<? extends Enum<?>, U>, U> T valueOfAttribute(
            U attributeValue, Class<? extends T> enumClass,
            Class<? extends T>... otherEnumClasses) {
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(enumClass), Stream.of(otherEnumClasses))
                .map(t -> {
                    try {
                        return valueOfAttribute(t, attributeValue); // won't compile
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "no enum constant, from " + enumClass + "
                        + and " + Arrays.toString(otherEnumClasses)
                        + ", for " + attributeValue));
    }
```

Comment: Do you realise that your declaration of `YourEnum` doesn't compile?

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: @Sweeper I just did realise. Applogies.

Comment: Use a sealed interface, loop over the permitted subclasses, then get the enum constants for each.